# Compare current date with stored one

Tags: android, date, compare

For an easteregg in my Android app, I have to compare the current date with a stored date - and I only need to know if it's the right month.

I know that `System.currentTimeMillis()` is the fastest way to get the current time but now I need to get the current month from that. I avoided String comparison for it's known flaws.

My awful implementation works but it really doesn't look correct and efficient:

```
if (Integer.parseInt((String) DateFormat.format("MM",System.currentTimeMillis()))==12) //xmas "easteregg"
        xmasBool=true;
```

Is there any more elegant solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a better solution:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(new Date()); // Date's default constructor gives you current time
xmasBool = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) == Calendar.DECEMBER;
```

Comment: Ofc. the "IF" was totally unnecessary and even tho I wanted to avoid using Calender, this seems to be the cleanest solution. Thank you all for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
```

And now you can compare the variable month with your stored month.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare a day or a month or both, the whole date by formatting `java.Util.Date` using [SimpleDateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Eg.

```
new SimpleDateFormat("dd").format(new java.util.Date())
```

gives you the "day" value. Similarly `"MM"` will give you the month. Use combination of those as per your requirement.

Store it in the same format and you have a common standard for comparison.